# React Fiber Mesh Element using useRef hook, 'ref.current' is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-fiber

Environment
Next JS, TypeScript, React Fiber

Code Snippet

```
import { useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber'
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'

interface PolyhedronCanvasProps {
    position: [number, number, number],
    polyhedron: any
}

const PolyhedronCanvas = ( props: PolyhedronCanvasProps ) => {
    const ref = useRef()     
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    useFrame((_, delta) => {  
        ref.current.rotation.x += delta
        ref.current.rotation.y += 0.5 * delta
    })

    return (
        <mesh 
            position={props.position}
            ref={ref}            
            onPointerDown={() => setCount((count + 1) % 3)}
            geometry={props.polyhedron[count]}
        >
            <meshPhongMaterial color={'lime'} wireframe/>
        </mesh>
    )
}

export default PolyhedronCanvas
```

```
ref.current.rotation.x += delta
ref.current.rotation.y += 0.5 * delta
```

I could probably run the next js application but I still got TypeScript error on those two lines with `'ref.current' is possibly 'undefined'`

Again I could able to run the project but I wanted to remove the TypeScript errors which makes my jsx files red in VS Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the type of the `ref` (see [docs](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/tutorials/typescript)):

```
import { Mesh } from 'three'

const ref = useRef<Mesh>(null)
```

Check if `ref.current` exists before assigning the values:

```
useFrame((_, delta) => {  
  if(ref.current) {
    ref.current.rotation.x += delta
    ref.current.rotation.y += 0.5 * delta
  }
})
```

Comment: Then I got `Property 'rotation' does not exist on type 'never'.` error.

Comment: `const ref = useRef()` I actually think I need to delare the useRef variable with Type but I am not able to find the right type for Mesh Tag.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: `three-types.d.ts(34, 5): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'MeshProps'`  I am seeing this error in the mesh tag `<mesh 
            position={props.position}
            ref={ref} `

Comment: `const ref = useRef<Mesh>(null) ` actually this works. Thanks!

Comment: You can edit your answer and I can do check mark.

Comment: Updated. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Object3D } from "three";

const ref = useRef();

useFrame((_, delta) => {
    if (ref.current) {
        const object3D = ref.current as Object3D;
        object3D.rotation.x += delta;
        object3D.rotation.y += 0.5 * delta;
    }
});
```